# Flex 4 Printing Error with dynamic components

Tags: apache-flex, printing, flex4, components, memory-address

I have a set of components that are added to my Flex 4 stage dynamically.

Problem 1:
How do I address these objects when adding them to print.I cant generate objects on the fly and append them because then the print manager does not wait for the dynamic data to populate.

I currently use the following code to address items dynamically which fails:

```
public function PrintDashPreview():void{
    var ItemsDrawn:int = 0;
    var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
    if(printJob.start()){
        for each (var item:Object in GetDashBoardPreviewItems.lastResult.DashboardItem)
        {
            ItemsDrawn ++
            this.addElement(dashPreview["flexShape" + TheID]);
            printJob.addObject(dashPreview["flexShape" + TheID]);
            this.removeElement(dashPreview["flexShape" + TheID]);

        }
        printJob.send()

    Alert.show('Sent: ' + ItemsDrawn + ' items to page for printing.','Print Progress Debug');
    }
}
```

How can I tell flex to grab these specific items and add them to the print job.

Problem 2:

How do I tell flex to lay each item out one below the other 2 per page.

Please and thank you for any help you can provide.

Regards
Craig Mc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe for printing dynamic content usually goes like this:

(1) Start the printJob:

```
printJob = new FlexPrintJob();
printJob.printAsBitmap = false;
printJob.start();
```

(2) Obtain the print page dimensions. Use it if you have overflowing content:

```
printerPageHeight = printJob.pageHeight;
printerPageWidth = printJob.pageWidth;
```

(3) Create all of the dynamic objects and wait for the corresponding **CREATION_COMPLETE** events:

```
var componentsToBeInitialized:Number = 0;
var pages:Array = [];
for each (var itemData:Object in dataProvider) {
    var component:UIComponent = new PageComponent();
    someContainerOnTheDisplayList.addChild(component);
    component.data = itemData;
    componentsToBeInitialized ++;
    pages.push(component);
    component.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, handlePageCompletion);
}
```

(4) Waiting for all **CREATION_COMPLETE** events:

```
function handlePageCompletion(e:Event):void {
    componentsToBeInitialized --;
    if (componentsToBeInitialized == 0)
        printAllPages();
}
```

(5) Print the pages:

```
function printAllPages():void {
   for each (var printPage:UIComponent in pages) {
   printJob.addObject(printPage);
   }         
   printJob.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , that makes sense.

So if I wanted 2 items per page, I would create a container in the display like a vgroup and then place two components into it, and then just attach the vgroup into the pages. That does make it all fit into place.

Thanks Vladimir.

One other question, I notice this works only on certain printers, have you had any problems printing certain content.

I noticed that when I print to a virtual printer it all works fine, but when I print to something other than a pdf or mdi printer, I get mixed printing results, usually all broken.

Any tips?

Comment: Don't know if that would change anything, but it worth trying to print with `printJob.printAsBitmap = true;` Let me know if that changed anything!

Comment: turns out after the first argument in AddObject adding second ,"ShowAll" totally changed the behavior its as if certain layers in the underlying components started getting drawn.

Comment: I can't recall experiencing such issues with printing. One thing you can do for debug purposes is to put on the Flash display the exact view you want to print - this might indicate layout issues, etc.

Comment: It all looks fine on screen, its only when using a 3rd party component called AnyChart, not sure why, but seems to be functional for now.

Comment: Question how are you able to see the variables in the functions, far as I know the printjob would not be in public scope?

Comment: The code above obviously belongs to a class, where the printJob is a class field and the functions are the methods.